# salt mixture problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Water with a small salt content (5 lb in 1000 gal) is flowing into a very salty lake at the rate of 4*10^5 gal/hr.  The salty water is flowing out at the rate of 10^5 gal/her. If at t=0 the volume of the lake is 10^9 gal, and its salt content is 10^7 lb, find the salt content at time t.  Assume that the salt is mixed uniformly with the water in the lake at all times.

I tried S'(t)=4E5(5 lb/1000g)-10^5(S/10^9) and solving for S, but that didn't work.  The final answer shouldn't have any e terms in it.